# Is it possible to reset the VWP time counter by visiting a third country after entering Canada from the US?

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program

After reading [UK Citizen flying to US, then Canada, then back to UK - How does this affect Visa Waiver Program?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/67023/4188) I am wondering:

1. If you are in the US, travel to Canada and re-enter your VWP clock didn't reset. This is classic.
2. There are countries, in particular in Central America where a brief visit does count as a "reset".
3. So what happens if you go USA-Canada-reset country-Canada-USA?

Comment: You mean beside the VWP clock resetting ?

Comment: It's pretty clear that going to the reset country resets the clock.  Presumably, the traveler would need to point out the relevant travel to the US border officer when re-entering the US, since it's likely that the border officer would otherwise not notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to, say, Guatemala (outside the 90-day clock area) for a short while before returning to the US via Canada, that will restore the clock. However, if you stay for close to 90 days in the US before doing this, then, at the US port of entry, the CBP officer is likely to assume you intend to live in the US by means of visa runs. If they assume this and you're unable to convince them otherwise, you will be refused entry and almost certainly prohibited from entering under the VWP again (meaning you'll have to apply for a visa)

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, you would also need to provide clear evidence of your visit to Guatemala.

Comment: @DJClayworth They do stamp the passport you know, so you Need to provide nothing